# Is the family of sets is algebra, sigma-algebra?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

$\mathcal A = \{A:= \bigcup_{i=1}^{m} I_i : I_1,...,I_m \in \mathbb I, I_i \cap I_j = \emptyset, i \not = j\}.$

$\mathbb I= \{ (a, b], (- \infty,b], (a, + \infty), (- \infty, + \infty)\}.$

Is $\mathcal A$ algebra, sigma-algebra?

**I started from:**

1) $\mathbb R \in \mathcal A$

2) Let $A = \bigcup_{i=1}^{m} I_i \in \mathcal A.$ Then $A^c = (\bigcup_{i=1}^{m} I_i)^c = \bigcap_{i=1}^{m} (I_i)^c = I_i^c\cap...\cap I_m^c \in \mathcal A.$

3) Let $A, B \in \mathcal A.$ Then $A \cup B = (\cup_{i=1}^{m} I_i') \bigcup (\cup_{i=1}^{m} I_i'')=\bigcup_{i=1}^{m} (I_i' \cup I_i'') \in \mathcal A.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z}(2n,2n+1]$ is not in $\mathcal A$ so $\mathcal A$ is not a sigma algebra.

To show it is an algebra you have to first show that any union of intervals of the type mentioned can be expressed as a disjoint union. The complement of a set in $\mathcal A$ is easy to compute.

Comment: Can you give some hints how to show that any union of intervals of the type mentioned can be expressed as a disjoint union?

Comment: $I_1\cup I_2\cup...\cup I_n=I_1\cup (I_2\setminus I_1) \cup...\cup (I_n\setminus (I_1 \cup I_2\cup...\I_{n-1})$. Next see what happens to $I_2\setminus I_1$. Can you see that this is a disjoint union of two intervals or  a single interval of the type we have?. Next look at $I_3\setminus I_1 \cup I_2$, etc.

Comment: Thank you! And the complement I can get in the similar way?

Comment: @Philip Yes,you can use similar arguments for the complement.